# Read A Line In Text File with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to read the numeric value of one line in a text file

```
color=7
```

so var color will = 7

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Split the string by `'='`, get the second value and turn it into an int:

```js
let data = 'color=7';
let color = parseInt(data.split('=')[1]);
console.log(color);
```

Do note that if the value after the = isn't a number in this case, the code will throw an excpetion so you might wanna catch it.